# Mandrill SMTP did not accept MAIL FROM: on 0.1% deliveries

Tags: php, email, mandrill

We are using Mandrill SMTP for sending mails from website build in PHP with Nette Framework. There are about 100 mails send daily and every 10-14 days one or two mails Mandrill refuses to send and website throws this exception:

> Nette\Mail\SmtpException: SMTP server did not accept MAIL FROM:< info@ourdomain >

Mail in FROM: address is correct, same as in other mails which are send correctly. Domain is properly configured (added to domain list in Mandrill), API key is ok, domain has correct DKIM DNS record.

Mails are send using Nette\Mail\SmtpMailer::send() - http://api.nette.org/2.2.9/source-Mail.SmtpMailer.php.html#69

Exception throws Nette\Mail\SmtpMailer::write() on this line - http://api.nette.org/2.2.9/source-Mail.SmtpMailer.php.html#168

I don't think this issue is related to Nette Framework SmtpMailer class, we are using this method to send mails on more websites (not using Mandrill) and everything work fine. Even with Mandrill it's about 1-2 delivery fails on 1000-1400 correctly delivered mails only.

Connection to SMTP server smtp.mandrillapp.com and AUTH LOGIN is always successful, error comes after that on MAIL FROM: only. Mandrill reputation of used account is EXCELLENT, deliverability rate 99.4%.

What can cause this situation? Can it be Mandrill [uptime](http://status.mandrillapp.com/) related?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. This is not related to your client or mandrill uptime or anything. The communication obviously works fine, but the smtp server refuses the address. You will have to ask the Mandrill support for the rason. Or, since some smtp servers add a reason why they refuse certain addresses, you might want to "play smtp client" yourself, so connect raw to the smtp server and "speak" smtp protocol, so that you can see the reason in the protocol reply.

Comment: What is reported in mandrill's log files?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Under Settings / API Logs there are no failed API calls (You don't have any failed API calls.)

Comment: @arkascha We are using one mail address in FROM: for all mail deliveries, so I don't think it's address related.

Comment: Why? You do not know the rules for a denial. For a mass mailing service like Mandrill it certainly does make sense to relate the specified from address against other meta data of the message and react to that.

Comment: @arkascha But the MAIL FROM: command is send right after AUTH LOGIN command and before all others commands like RCPT, DATA etc. so Mandrill still doesn't know content of mail...

Comment: That is true, indeed! Hm, strange, I never experienced that issue with Mandrill. So again I would suggest to ask them. We usually received a reply, though not always to our satisfaction...

Comment: @arkascha ok thanks for help, I will contact technical support